# What version of Cassandra does Fluent Cassandra v0.7.0.3 support?

Tags: c#, cassandra

What version of Cassandra does Fluent Cassandra v0.7.0.3 support?

Comment: You are asking the same question again and again; well almost same though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585795/which-version-of-cassandra-does-aquiles-v0-7-0-6-support

Comment: This question relates to Fluent Cassandra which is different to the other question. And the question would not get the well ranked in the search engines if they were merged. Sorry if this is bad practice. But the page title of the page is made up of the question. And a user is likely going to search in Google for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The goal of this project is to keep the interface in sync with **the latest version of Cassandra** and make it as easy as possible for .NET developers to start, adopt and program against the Cassandra database."

^ This was taken from the [github readme page](https://github.com/managedfusion/fluentcassandra/blob/master/README.md).  They aim to keep up to date.

On May 21st there was a commit which reads "updated to cassandra 0.7.6 and thrift 0.6.0"

It seems to have incorporated changes to work with 0.8.2 as of May 25th.