# Which version of Cassandra does Aquiles v0.7.0.6 support?

Tags: c#, cassandra

What version of **Cassandra** does **Aquiles** v0.7.0.6 support?

Comment: Surely you could have asked this along with your other qusetion?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585771/what-version-of-cassandra-does-fluent-cassandra-v0-7-0-3-support

Comment: Hi Jon, I could have, but the question would not get the well ranked in the search engines then. Sorry if this is bad practice. But the page title of the page is made up of the question. And a user is likely going to search in Google for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at their [codeplex page](http://aquiles.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Aquiles.VersionHistory&referringTitle=Documentation) it seems it supports Apache Cassandra 0.6.2 or above.

Comment: Thanks Fishcake, I had not seen the version history page. And the home page was slightly confusing as it mentions 0.8